# redirect url with mod_rewrite at .htaccess and keeping domain ending

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I try to get something like that:

`www.domain1.com/some-ending` or `domain1.com/some-ending` to `www.domain2.com/some-ending`

If an URL is called with or without www, the second domain should be opened with the corresponding ending (/some-ending), like a variable.

This is my code so far, I just need to get the ending in there:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain1\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain2.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: And what is the problem with this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks ok , I just added an optional "/" to the pattern so that it can also accept a url ending with a "/" And a "NC" flag for the case-insenstivity.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain1\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ http://www.domain2.com/$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```